# How can I move a single git repo to work with multiple TFS workspaces?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working on a project that is branched in TFS, so I have set up multiple workspaces on my local machine, let's call them: (sprint, uat, live).

Another part of the project source code is in a git repository and has a sprint, uat, live branch.

I cannot move the entire project into either TFS or git at the moment.
The setup for the solution has the git repository as a subdirectory of the solution in the TFS workspace (this is due to a script that runs in a the directory that uses relative paths).

I am working on the uat branch at the moment so I have my workspaces set up like so:

> C:\path\sprint
>      C:\path\uat
>      C:\path\uat\gitRepo
>      C:\path\live

Since my git repository is mapped to a single directory on my local machine and I can `$git checkout` different branches which will update my file system, but the source will stay in the same location on the file system.

I want to work on sprint branch, so I would like move my local git repository from `C:\path\uat\gitRepo` to `C:\path\sprint\gitRepo` and then I can `$git checkout sprint` and start working.

Is this possible? If so, how do I change the location of the repository on disk using git cli or Atlassian SourceTree (currently v1.4.1.0)? Or should I be working in a different way while I'm forced to use both VCSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many git working copies as you like tracking the same remote repository, so I would suggest you check out sprint and uat branches into the relevant TFS working copies and go from there.

As an example:

C:\path\sprint\gitRepo ( `git checkout sprint` )

C:\path\uat\gitRepo ( `git checkout uat` )

HTH